# How to enable HEAD method on API Gateway with Terraform

Tags: aws-api-gateway, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I've tried adding the following to my currently working apigateway API setup

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "enable_head_request" {
  provider         = "aws.default"
  rest_api_id      = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.petshop.id}"
  resource_id      = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.petshop.root_resource_id}"
  http_method      = "HEAD"
  authorization    = "NONE"
#  api_key_required = "False"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "enable_head_request" {
  provider                = "aws.default"
  rest_api_id             = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.petshop.id}"
  resource_id             = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.petshop.root_resource_id}"
  http_method             = "${aws_api_gateway_method.enable_head_request.http_method}"
  integration_http_method = "POST"
  type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
  uri                     = "${aws_lambda_function.petshop.invoke_arn}"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "200_for_head_request" {
  provider    = "aws.default"
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.petshop.id}"
  resource_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.petshop.root_resource_id}"
  http_method = "${aws_api_gateway_method.enable_head_request.http_method}"
  status_code = "200"
}
```

However after deploying and trying to curl the endpoint I get;

```
curl --head https://test.com
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Thu, 01 Mar 2018 18:47:07 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 42
Connection: keep-alive
x-amzn-RequestId: f1811ce9-1d80-11e8-b15c-cf44af523470
x-amzn-ErrorType: MissingAuthenticationTokenException
```

**EDIT:**
The issue is indeed that the deployment is not redeployed. But I found a better way to do it as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: should the `curl` command be something like: `curl --head "xxx: xxx" https://test.com`?

Comment: You need to deploy again after removing authorisation. There was a recent question that had the exact same problem. Terraform doesn't automatically redeploy the API Gateway when you apply because it doesn't handle the API Gateway release model well at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing Authentication Token on Unauthenticated Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48955987/missing-authentication-token-on-unauthenticated-method)

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I have been able to add a new GET request to a different path with no issue

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the deployment does not get redeployed. Here's a better way to do it than in the linked question

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "petshop" {
  provider    = "aws.default"
  stage_description = "${md5(file("apigateway.tf"))}"
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.petshop.id}"
  stage_name  = "prod"
}
```

This saves you redeploying on every minor change and will only be triggered by changes in the `apigateway.tf` file